# Stationary and limiting distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, limit-theorems

Consider a CT Markov Process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ with state space $E\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Are there any general conditions under which a stationary distribution $\pi$ for $X$ is also a limiting distribution and viceversa?

Any useful reference will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Markov chains, a very useful condition is Harris recurrence,
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_chain.
This has been generalized to continuous time, see
https://www.jstor.org/stable/3690386?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents